# How is Google Maps main view implemented?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, opengl-es

I need to implement something similar with the default Google's MAPS application.

Basically a "view" containing image tiles which resemble a map and supports all kind of gestures (pinch zoom, etc).

Which is the best optimal approach to implement this?

- canvas and drawables
- OpenGL
- other?

How exactly the main view (with the map) should be implemented, from layout to used APIs.

Comment: Check this blog here for some ideas: http://ghoscher.me/2012/03/09/building-a-map-app-for-android/